# Mock modular forms of higher rank?

Tags: modular-forms

It appears that mock modular forms are currently defined as the ``holomorhic part" of a harmonic weak Mass form on the upper half plane (with regard to certain modular subgroup).

Is there any generalization of this concept to higher dimensional Shimura varieties?

Comment: A good, obvious question. An elementary viewpoint will not be effective... :)  Growth issues versus tame growth are not trivial, nor are representation-type issues. :)  Was there a specific issue in mind>

Comment: Was thinking out the implication of the term "being the holomorphic part". The generating function of Hurwitz class numbers, as a mock modular form, is associated to Zagier's Eisenstein series of weight 3/2. recently noticed that some geometric generating functions are the ``holomorphic part" of some interesting Eisenstein series on Siegel upper half plane. Possibly some Eisenstein series contribute to a subset of the imagined generalization of harmonic weak mass form.

Comment: Paul, is there a representation theoretic characterization of the space of harmonic weak mass forms on the upper half plane? (They are functions on Shimura curves, though not necessarily L^2.)